# Force SharePoint Site Title to be shown in the explorer view instead of Site Url

Tags: office-365, sub-site

When I open the list of subsites in windows explorer view (from IE), it shows the list of Subsites with their URL as folder name

Is there a way to get the  Site title displayed instead of the displaying URL?

P.S I changed the URL and its getting  reflected in explorer view, but I don't want to change the URL. I want the Site title to be shown instead of URL

Answer (score 1):

From memory the WebClient service is used to access a SharePoint Library as a webdav resource, so therefore the address shown would always be the address of the resource you're accessing... you wouldn't be able to use the web title property as it would not be a valid url.

Comment: so are there no options to force it to use the web title property?